# jquery json with arrays with numerical keys

Tags: jquery, json

If i have a php file that outputs json data with numerical keys, like

```
<?php
$array[1] = "abcd";
$array[2] = "efgh";
$array[3] = "1234";
$array[4] = "5678";

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

how do i access the value for say key 4? The integer in "data.4" below is breaking the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "http://localhost:8888/myapp/json/json_data",
         async: false,
         beforeSend: function(x) {
          if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
           x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
          }
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
        //$("#box").html(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        $("#box").append("<br/>" + data.4)
     }
    });
```

Comment: Can't do it like this, Nope. Do -> `data["4"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use brackets to access the property: `data['4']`.

Note: Your PHP is **not** returning an array, but an object: `{"1":"abcd","2":"efgh","3":"1234","4":"5678"}`.

PS. You've got a typo in your `overrideMimeType`. You shouldn't have to override this though, because you're using jQuery. For an alternative, see [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: I should stop responding with my answers in comments. +1!

Comment: If the array keys weren't manually set on the php side, `json_encode` would return an array instead of an object.